# Authentication in angularjs with Spring MVC 1 different origin (gulp+ jetty)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, gulp, jetty

My application back-end using spring mvc  server as jetty server and front end is angularjs  server as gulp.

Server ( jetty server) base url is

```
localhost:8080
```

front end ( gulp server)  base url is

```
localhost:4000
```

when  try to login using  angularjs ui routing, url is

```
http://localhost:4000/#login
```

and Rest request url

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

with request method is  post then   get successful message

after  try to access some variable from server using

```
`http://localhost:4000/#/loginDetails`
```

i get login failed message.

but i can  access get request from server directory using Browser ( after rest login success)

eg

```
http://localhost:8080/someVariableServer
```

CorsFilter

```
    public class CorsFilter implements Filter {


        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }


        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            System.out.println("Adding Access Control Response Headers");
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }

}
```

My Question is

Is it possible use session for  authentication app  with different origin?
Any solution?